# I feel like this regex pattern should work but it doesn't

Tags: regex, string

I'm new to regex and honestly not that experienced.
I got this regex pattern that I want to try and use.

```
/(a..e.)([a-zA-Z])/gi
```

The plan is that it should match any words that follow the pattern. So I can loop over a list of words and it locks A in the first slot at E in the second to last spot. And it finds all words that matches this. However I've run into an issue. I expect it to match with the word ADDER however it doesn't. When I remove the last period, so that the pattern becomes

```
/(a..e)([a-zA-Z])/gi
```

It does work. Shouldn't these two basically be the same? Since we're using a wildcard dot?

Using the https://regexr.com/

Comment: The first attempt tries to match an additional (6th) character, in the second capture group (in parentheses). As you removed one dot in the second attempt, there are now 5 characters to be matched.

Comment: Your regexp expects 6 characters, but `ADDER` has only 5

Comment: I think you misunderstood the meaning of a dot **or** the meaning of your second capture group. It's not quite clear what exactly it is you are after. Maybe you meant to make the 2nd capture group optional?

Comment: Yes it turns out I misunderstood the 2nd capturing group. Peoples answers here have explained everything I needed to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(a..e.)([a-zA-Z])` pattern looks for an `a`, after which there must be any two chars (other than line break chars), then an `e` letter, and then any single char other than line break chars. This pattern neither guarantees you match a whole word, nor that the chars matched with `.` will be letters.

`/(a..e.)([a-zA-Z])/gi` is not equal to `/(a..e)([a-zA-Z])/gi` as they match and consume different strings. Since there is no `.` after `e`, the second pattern matches fewer chars, not allowing any single char other than line break chars after `e` letter before any single letter (the last pattern part).

To match words starting with the `a` letter, followed with two more letters, then an `e` letter, and then one more letter you can use

```js
/\ba[a-z]{2}e[a-z]\b/gi
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VxRXjP/1). *Details*:

- `/gi` - match all occurrences (`g`) in a case insensitive way (`i`)
- `\b` - matches a word boundary
- `a`  - `a` / `A`
- `[a-z]{2}` - two ASCII letters
- `e` - an `e` letter
- `[a-z]` - any ASCII letter
- `\b` - matches a word boundary.